# Cannot modify my array - Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: arrays, swift

I know I'm doing something wrong but I do not know what..

All I would like to do here is add some `pet` to my `Array<Pet>`

What am I doing wrong here?

The error is

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

```
import UIKit

struct Person {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var pets: [String]
}

final class City {
    let people = [Person]()
    
    func addPetFor(id: UUID, newPets: [String]) {
        self.people.findPerson(by: id).pets.append(contentsOf: newPets) //<-- error Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Person {
    func findPerson(by id: UUID) -> Person {
        let foundPerson = self.first { person in
            person.id == id
        }
        return foundPerson!
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of failed attempt to append an array to an array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you, your `findPerson` method is returning an immutable struct, so you can't edit it.

There are a few solutions to this -- two are included in the code sample below:

```
final class City {
    var people = [Person]()
    
    func addPetFor(id: UUID, newPets: [String]) {
        guard let index = self.people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) else {
            assertionFailure("Not found")
            return
        }
        self.people[index].pets.append(contentsOf: newPets)
    }
    
    func addPetFor2(id: UUID, newPets: [String]) {
        self.people = self.people.map {
            if $0.id == id {
                var personCopy = $0
                personCopy.pets.append(contentsOf: newPets)
                return personCopy
            } else {
                return $0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases, the code has a reference to where the `Person` belongs in the `people` array, so it can modify it. Note that `people` also has to be `var`, not `let`, for the same reason -- it needs to be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Structs have value semantics. When you pass them around/assign them to things, they get copied, and unless it is `var`, you can't mutate them.

Return values are not `var`s, you cannot change a return value. You can put it in a `var` variable first, and then append to `pets`

```
var person = self.people.findPerson(by: id)
person.pets.append(contentsOf: newPets)
```

This makes the compiler error go away, but `person` here is a *copy* of the return value, so your modification here doesn't actually change the things in the `self.people` array. `self.people` is declared a `let` constant in the first place, so you better change that too:

```
var people = [Person]()
```

One way is to have `findPerson` return the index of the person found:

```
extension Array where Element == Person {
    func findPerson(by id: UUID) -> Int {
        let foundPerson = self.firstIndex { person in
            person.id == id
        }
        return foundPerson!
    }
}
```

This way, you can do:

```
let index = self.people.findPerson(by: id)
self.people[index].pets.append(contentsOf: newPets)
```

Note how I am doing things directly on `self.people`, rather than through another variable. `addPetFor` also needs to be marked `mutating`.

Another way is to have `findPerson` take a closure, and you write in that closure what you want to do with the found person:

```
extension Array where Element == Person {
    mutating func findPerson(by id: UUID, andDo block: (inout Person) -> Void) -> Int {
        let index = self.firstIndex { person in
            person.id == id
        }
        block(&self[index!])
    }
}
```

Note how `findPerson` is now marked `mutating`, because it now mutates the array (`self`). `self[index]` is passed by `inout`, which is kind of like "by reference".

Then you can do:

```
self.people.findPerson(by: id) {
    $0.pets.append(contentsOf: newPets)
}
```